# how to use Firebase Cloud Messaging to send "data" type message in android when app closed

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working on an android chat app which is using latest version of firebase sdk, and with that I am using **Firebase Realtime Database**.

Now, the thing is that if someone lets say '**A**' send a message to '**B**' then that message is added to a node say '**Message**' in Realtime Database and then '**B**' is continously listening to this node for data changes and hence would get that message instantly.

But, the problem occurs when the android app is closed(**not killed**) and then when '**A**' send the message to '**B**' then how can I listen to that message.

I am not talking of just displaying a notification for that message to user '**B**', that is done by me using "**Notification**" type message using FCM,
But what I want is that when I receiver that message I want to run an activity within the app that would then handle the Firebase Listners Triggering.

As coming across various answers on stackoverflow, they mentioned to write some server side code or some mentioned to use "**data**" type message, but what I want to avoid writing any server side code , and want to knwo how to send "**data**" type message so that I can receiver notification even when app is closed and would run the activity as mentioned by me in "**onMessageReceived()**" callback.

Comment: The only secure way to send push notifications with FCM is through a backend.  You really should go that route.

Comment: @Doug Stevenson but i want to be able to send the Notification from the sender itself so that whenever the sender is sending a message then at the same time he may also notify the receiving user and if the receiving user is having his app closed then he still would get that message through on messagereceived()

Comment: I really dont want to go to that backend solution, because i already gave too much time to this app and maybe dealing with backend would require me to learn something new

Comment: That's not a good idea because the FCM API requires service account credentials, and you should never expose those through your app for security reasons.

Comment: Umm, so any other way around it?

Comment: I just want it the way whatsapp does

Comment: Every major app has a backend these days.

Comment: And so in case of firebase, does it provides anything like that backend stuff?!

Comment: Or you talking about running this api specific code through google cloud functions?!

Comment: Cloud Functions is one of nearly infinite choices.

Comment: And as far as i know the free tier of firebase plan have limited cloud function invocations so that would add up extra cost to my app, any other free or cheap alternative?